# Array Items Filtering Ionic 3

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I have implemented array list. It is populated from fire-base. I want to search through that list. When the page is loaded first time, It do not display any listed item. But if I type something on search input then it shows the list items. I tried ngZone but it did not work, here I will give you full source code.

**NOTE : after input something on search always display items, but initially empty**

[image: Here is the problem exactly what i have]

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>    
    <ion-searchbar [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" [formControl]="searchControl" (ionInput)="onSearchInput()"></ion-searchbar>

    <div *ngIf="searching" class="spinner-container">
        <ion-spinner></ion-spinner>
    </div>

    <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
            {{item.client_meeting_schedule_client_name}}
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**DONE_TASK.ts**

```
export class DoneTasksPage {

  searchTerm: string = '';
  searchControl: FormControl;
  items: any;
  searching: any = false;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public oDataListProvider: DataListProvider, private oNgZone: NgZone) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.setFilteredItems();
    this.searchControl.valueChanges.debounceTime(700).subscribe(search => {
      this.searching = false;
      this.setFilteredItems();
    });
  }

  onSearchInput() {
    this.searching = true;
  }

  setFilteredItems() {
    this.oNgZone.run(() => {
      this.items = this.oDataListProvider.filterItems(this.searchTerm);
    })
  }

}
```

**DATA_LIST_PROVIDER**

```
export class DataListProvider {


  items = [];
  public ClientSchedules: Array<any> = [];
  clientSchedulesRef: any;
  whereClause: string;

  constructor(private oAngularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private oNgZone: NgZone) {

    this.whereClause = "true_false_true_false";

    //Client schedule node refference
    this.clientSchedulesRef = this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('/Client_meeting_schedule').orderByChild("client_meeting_schedule_valid_status").equalTo(this.whereClause);
    //Above sequence of equal IsActive true / IsDelete false / IsDone true / IsNotDone false

    this.clientSchedulesRef.on('value', client_Schedules_Snapshot => {
      this.oNgZone.run(() => {
        // Here we'll work with the list
        client_Schedules_Snapshot.forEach(clientsSheduleSnap => { 
          this.items.push(clientsSheduleSnap.val());
        });
      });
    });
  }

  filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.client_meeting_schedule_client_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: after  `push` operation try `this.items=[...this.items]`

Comment: please give me more details @Vikas

Comment: What I meant is put the block of code i share after your forEach Method n let me know if it works

Comment: no it's not working,I tried. @Vikas

Comment: is it possible to provide a stackblitz?

Comment: no it's not @Vikas

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182181/discussion-between-thusharahettigoda-and-vikas).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Issue

Data is not loading in place because items are not available at the time since items are loading synchronously. Even after data loading we are notifying the Angular that data is available.

### Fix

So lets handle these `Asynchronous` call by `Subject` in Data Provider. It will notify the Component whenever items are available.

```
import { Observable, Subject } from 'rxjs';

export class DataListProvider {

   //-- Observable ------
   private subject = new Subject<any>();

   sendItems(items) {
      this.subject.next(items);
   }

   getItems(): Observable<any> {
      return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
   //-- Observable ------ end

  items = [];
  public ClientSchedules: Array<any> = [];
  clientSchedulesRef: any;
  whereClause: string;

  constructor(private oAngularFireDatabase: AngularFireDatabase, private oNgZone: NgZone) {

    this.whereClause = "true_false_true_false";

    //Client schedule node refference
    this.clientSchedulesRef = this.oAngularFireDatabase.database.ref('/Client_meeting_schedule').orderByChild("client_meeting_schedule_valid_status").equalTo(this.whereClause);
    //Above sequence of equal IsActive true / IsDelete false / IsDone true / IsNotDone false

    this.clientSchedulesRef.on('value', client_Schedules_Snapshot => {
      this.oNgZone.run(() => {
        // Here we'll work with the list
        client_Schedules_Snapshot.forEach(clientsSheduleSnap => { 
          this.items.push(clientsSheduleSnap.val());
        });
       this.sendItems(this.items); //notify all Observer
      });
    });
  }

  filterItems(searchTerm) {
    return this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.client_meeting_schedule_client_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm.toLowerCase()) > -1;
    });
  }

}
```

### DONE_TASK.ts

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public oDataListProvider: DataListProvider, private oNgZone: NgZone) {
    this.searchControl = new FormControl();

    this.oDataListProvider.getItems().subscribe(items=>{
       this.items = items;
    })
```

}

> Note : Edited in Editor directly so there could be some typo or syntactical error. Please correct if needed.

Comment: this is works. but i now if i navigate to another page and came back it is again empty. @Sunil Singh

Comment: Constructor will be called only once. Better you move this code to `ngOnInit()`